# I am trying to scrape the names of the members of the U.S. Congress from Ballotpedia

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-inspector

I am trying to scrape the names of the members of the U.S. Congress from this page (https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_current_members_of_the_U.S._Congress) on Ballotpedia with Python. This code that I am using has worked fine in the past (as recently as last week). Now, instead of giving me the names of legislators, it is giving me the page title: ",List_of_current_members_of_the_U.S._Congress".

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_current_members_of_the_U.S._Congress']

temp_dict = {}

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in 
soup.select('table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter')]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, 
orient='index').transpose()
df.to_csv('3-New Congressmen.csv')
```

I believe the problem is line 13:

```
temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in 
soup.select('table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter')]
```

I tried taking out

```
table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter
```

and replacing it with

```
bptable gray sortable tablesorter tablesorter-default tablesortera6303b5b2311e jquery-tablesorter
```

and I would also need to add a new line for the U.S. House since the above line would only give senators

```
bptable gray sortable tablesorter tablesorter-default tablesorter2e5ec79e370a5 jquery-tablesorter
```

However, this new code gives me the exact same title that I got with my original code.

Do you have any recommendations for me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in the tables from the website, pandas has a built-in function `read_html()` (package lxml needed) to scrape it and put it directly into a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_current_members_of_the_U.S._Congress']    
test = pd.read_html(list[0]) #gets all the tables from the url    
print(test[3]) #get the different tables by index
```

output:

```
                      Office             Name       Party Date assumed office
0         U.S. Senate Kansas      Jerry Moran  Republican     January 5, 2011
1         U.S. Senate Kansas   Roger Marshall  Republican     January 3, 2021
2       U.S. Senate Michigan      Gary Peters  Democratic     January 6, 2015
3       U.S. Senate Michigan  Debbie Stabenow  Democratic     January 3, 2001
4       U.S. Senate Virginia        Tim Kaine  Democratic     January 3, 2013
..                       ...              ...         ...                 ...
95      U.S. Senate Missouri      Josh Hawley  Republican     January 3, 2019
96  U.S. Senate Pennsylvania       Pat Toomey  Republican     January 5, 2011
97  U.S. Senate Pennsylvania    Bob Casey Jr.  Democratic     January 4, 2007
98          U.S. Senate Utah         Mike Lee  Republican     January 5, 2011
99          U.S. Senate Utah      Mitt Romney  Republican     January 3, 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

The best wait is just to add the names to a list using this style `padding-left:10px;text-align:center;` which is unique to U.S. Senate members names.

This should do the trick:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}
url="https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_current_members_of_the_U.S._Congress"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
tds = soup.findAll("td", {"style": "padding-left:10px;text-align:center;"})

names=[]
for td in tds:
    names.append(td.getText())
```